# Netsuite - rest api to retrieve report result

Tags: api, rest, report, netsuite

I would like to create report in Netsuite and to use the report result in API rest in order to retrieve the data,
Is it feasible ?

Comment: Yes, this is feasible through both creating a restlet, via the soap api, but I am not sure if the REST api supports it.  That said, there isn't enough information in this question for the community to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you, i would like to create a report from Currencies object that we will pull out data everyday by soap/rest api